# WPF Visual States & changing colors

Tags: wpf, styles

My WPF application needs to have two different color schemes based upon time of day, a day-mode and a night-mode.  I'm trying to modify the template used by a third-party WPF control so it will work with the different color schemes.

The control in question uses visual states to define the transition from selected to unselected:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar:CalendarButton}">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                <Chromes:ButtonChrome x:Name="SelectionChrome" CornerRadius="1" Margin="2" RenderNormal="False" RenderSelected="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsFocused}" RenderHighlighted="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" />
                <Border x:Name="TodayVisual" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF282828"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF5F5F5F" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I need to change the `Background`, `BorderBrush`, and `Foreground` properties of the `ButtonChrome` control when the visual state is "Selected".  How do I do this?

Comment: I've resolved this issue, but it turned out that I didn't need to do anything to the `ButtonChrome` control.  The control I needed to modify was the `ContentPresenter` and I got that working.  Basically, @CodeWarrior is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that on most controls that have a Chrome elements (whether they be Microsoft or other parties controls), it is necessary to remove the chrome element, and re-construct it by hand as they often do not provide a method to change them (i.e. no way to substitute a template).

However, if anyone else has a better way, I am all ears.